# Weird text artifacts when dynamically changing it

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have the following code that changes the text every second. When this happens, weird lines go above the text (google chrome). I am using the google font `Press Start 2P`.

```
<p>{countdown.days}d {countdown.hours}h {countdown.minutes}m {countdown.seconds}s</p>
```

Is there some sort of CSS or changes in my html that can avoid these artifacts?

[image]

So far, I've tried adding the following to this element with no luck:

1. Adding `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);`
2. Adding `outline: 1px solid transparent;`

Comment: Can you put up a runnable snippet? In particular, how are you changing the text, is there any CSS involved?

Comment: No css involved, just changing the text via javascript timeout function @AHaworth

Answer (score 0):

Is is the encoding method you are using? UTF-8 is buggy sometimes but ISO/IEC 8859-1 fixes artefacts whenever I've used it in the past :)

Comment: This did not do anything unfortunately